# differentiating between the closing of a window using window.close and other means (like clicking on cross)

Tags: onunload

I wish to find out whether the window was closed using **window.close()** or by manually (like clicking on the cross or refreshing, or Alt + F4). For that, I can check whether the unload event is called, because, as I checked for Chrome, the unload event is not being called when **window.close()** is being executed

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#close').click(function(){
    window.close();
});
$(window).unload(function(){
    alert("hello");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="close" value="close"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanted  to know whether this is specified behaviour, or varies with browsers